# Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Quote) with the same id "429" already exist

Tags: php, magento

I am getting this error whenever I join the reports/quote_collection with the sales/quote_item table. I am trying to create an abandoned cart report for unregistered users. I need to display all items in the abandoned carts.

Please see code below:

```
$this->addFieldToFilter('items_count', array('neq' => '0'))
     ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', '1')
     ->addSubtotal($storeIds, $filter)
     ->setOrder('updated_at');
$this->getSelect()->joinInner(
     array('quote_items' => $this->getTable('sales/quote_item')),
            'quote_items.quote_id = main_table.entity_id',
            'name');
if (is_array($storeIds) && !empty($storeIds)) {
     $this->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
}

return $this;
```

How do I work around this error? Is there a way to display all the items?

Comment: Hi Victor! Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest that you head over to http://magento.stackexchange.com, the guys over there know a lot about Magento!

Answer (score 2):

This message occurs when Magento tries to add the same item twice to a collection because JOIN query result contains it multiple times.

You can avoid this with a GROUP BY on the primary key like this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id')
```